# Rxjs wrapping other libraries functions from D3 (Observable)

Tags: javascript, ajax, d3.js, observable, rxjs

I am just not getting this concept and am looking for enlightenment.  I am trying to Observe when data is fetched but have got the process mixed up. this is what I have so far. The ajax request is done with d3.tsv.

```
var test = Rx.Observable.just(
    d3.tsv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/3885304/raw/37bd91278846c053188a130a01770cddff023590/data.tsv", 
        function(d) {
          return {
            letter: d.letter,
            frequency: +d.frequency
          };
        }, 
        function(error, rows) {
          console.log('mytest2',rows);
        }
    )
);

var observer = Rx.Observer.create(
  function (x) { console.log('onNext: %s', x); },
  function (e) { console.log('onError: %s', e); },
  function () { console.log('onCompleted'); });

var subscription = test.subscribe(observer);
```

While this ajax request technically works, all of the Observable functions happen before the data arrives. How would I construct this where my 'onNext' log gives me the data instead of only getting it inside of the d3.tsv function?

Comment: "I am just not getting this concept and am looking for enlightenment" I know the feeling :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are RxJS operators dedicated to convert callbacks into observables (`.fromCallback`, `.fromNodeCallback`). However they will not work here, as they expect ONE callback, and that callback is the last parameter. Here you have two callbacks, one for success, one for result. I am not aware of any special operator for that case, so I would recommend that you use a custom helper function.

> ```
> function d3fn (url, success_handler, error_handler) {
>   success_handler ({
>     letter : 'letter',
>     frequency : 9
>   });
> }
>
> var d3 = {tsv : d3fn};
>
> function fromD3Callback (d3fn, ctx) {
> return function () {
>   var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
>   var subject = new Rx.AsyncSubject();
>
>   function success_handler () {
>     subject.onNext.apply(subject, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
>     subject.onCompleted();
>   }
>
>   function error_handler () {
>     subject.onError(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
>   }
>
>   args.push(success_handler);
>   args.push(error_handler);
>
>   d3fn.apply(ctx, args);
>   return subject.asObservable();
> }
> }
>
> var test = fromD3Callback(d3.tsv)("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/3885304/raw/37bd91278846c053188a130a01770cddff023590/data.tsv")
>   .map(function(d) {
>           return {
>             letter: d.letter,
>             frequency: +d.frequency
>           };
>         })
>   .catch(function(error, rows) {
>           console.log('mytest2',rows);
>           return Rx.Observable.throw({error: error, rows: rows});
>         });
>
> var observer = Rx.Observer.create(
>   function (x) { console.log('onNext: %o', x); },
>   function (e) { console.log('onError: %s', e); },
>   function () { console.log('onCompleted'); });
>
> var subscription = test.subscribe(observer);
> ```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  Sadly it did not work, but it got me thinking how to get to the right answer. I looked further into .fromNodeCallback and got that working.  The problem is I don't  know how to turn that working code into one with a filter i.e. .map, .flatmap, .filter and so on.  I posted the answer below if you have any suggestions.  If it includes a new Rx.AsyncSubject() even better because I think that is the direction I need to go.

Comment: corrected. jsfiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/n1ugv4g4/1/. This answers the question you asked. If you have an extension to that question or another one, please post a new question, unless it is a trivial matter.

Comment: This mostly answers my question.  I have updated the fiddle to have the d3 library and this returns the first item of the data set.  http://jsfiddle.net/53dg04ju/2/ My goal is to return the whole data set like my solution but with the flexibility of your answer. if you can update that would be great.

Comment: I have to confess I don't know anything about D3. Should I understand that the callback is called for each row? My code assumes that it is called only once, that's why I complete immediately after emitting the first item. If that's the case, it should be enough to remove the `.onCompleted` part of the solution. Cf. http://jsfiddle.net/53dg04ju/4/. On the downside, you know have no way of completing the subject, unless you d3 function has such an event.

Answer (score 1):

I have found an answer to my problem but would love a better one.  What I have figured out is this:

```
var url = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/3885304/raw/37bd91278846c053188a130a01770cddff023590/data.tsv"

var fetch = Rx.Observable.fromNodeCallback(d3.tsv);

var source = fetch(url, function(d) {
  return {
    letter: d.letter,
    frequency: +d.frequency
  };
})

var observer = Rx.Observer.create(
  function (o) {
        console.log('Next: success!', o);
    },
    function (err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
    },
    function () {
        console.log('Completed');
    });

var subscription = source.subscribe(observer);
```

My only problem is I don't know how to perform filtering off of this so I would be open to a better solution.